# Google Script- Convert Date to Epoch Time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I've been working on this for a long time and haven't quite found anything that fits what I need.

Right now, I have an array of dates- all of them look like this -

> Sun Mar 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT).

I'm looking for a way to convert that into

> 1364688000

Only through Google Script.

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 14):

```
=(A3-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400
```

With A3 being something like "2/20/2018"

Comment: Brillant and very fast!

Answer (score 3):

The `getTime()` method applied to a date returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch reference in JavaScript, ie what you are looking for.

```
Logger.log(new Date(2013,3,31,0,0,0,0).getTime());
```

Your value is in seconds, so we can divide /1000

but the value you are showing is not correct, result has an offset of 31 days in GMT 0 ... How are you getting the value `1364688000` ?

test code (script properties in UTC (GMT 0 without daylight savings)

```
function timeInMsSinceOrigin(){
  var val = new Date(2013,3,31,0,0,0,0).getTime()/1000;// in seconds
  var offset = val-1364688000; //in seconds too
  Logger.log('value = '+val+ '   offset : '+offset/3600+' hours  ='+offset/(3600*24)+' days');
}
```

Logger result :  `value = 1367366400   offset : 744 hours  =31 days`

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well- I have an array with those values ("Sun Mar 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT +700 (ICT)"...) to convert that into the Epoch Time (134688000).

Comment: well, the code above gives you the way to convert them easily... what else do you want to know ? And can you explain where this 31 days offset comes from ? or do you want the offset value to be converted automatically to the epoch value of the first day in the month ?

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the code. I have no idea where the offset comes from. I'll look into it but I'll probably just include the variable offset. As for the number, the debugger indicated that for March 31, it would take the value from Google Spreadsheets (3-31-2014) and enter it like this [(new Date(1364662800000))]

Comment: when you read a date from a spredsheet you don't **need** to convert it to the JS native value, it is actually already a date object... you can use all the date methods on it as it is.